# Since the Earth is moving through space, do we experience time dilation?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, relativity, time-dilation, relative-motion

What I mean is, the Earth orbits around the sun at around 30km/s, while I understand that this isn't a very high velocity does time dilation still occur to say a person who is completely stationary in space. And one last thing, the earth rotates at a higher velocity at the equator than at the poles, so would time dilation also occur there? So that people at the equator travel at a slower time relative to the poles? Again, I know that to see observable effects of time dilation you need to reach extremely high velocities and that these velocities would only result in a very tiny time dilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When thinking about such relativistic problems, one should always clearly define who the observer is and who he observes.

If you think Earth to be a reference frame of the observer, Earth is not moving w.r.t itself, therefor we don't see time dilation on our self. But for an observer on Sun, Earth is moving and there is a time dilation, as observed from Sun.

Similarly an observer on pole sees people on equator moving w.r.t him. Therefore there is a time dilated for people on equator as observed by pole-observer.